# Regex to match second number in a group of numbers from the second row

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match the second number from the second row in a string looking like:

`Total fara TVA                                     TVA                                          Total 171,11 RON                                         32,51 RON                                    203,62 RON`

What I want: `32,51`

What I'm trying regexr.com/64to5 : `Total(?:\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)){1}`

What I get: `171,11`

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Use `\bTotal\s*\d+(?:,\d+)?\D+(\d+(?:,\d+)?)`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Could you please tell me how to capture the last value, too? `203,62`

Comment: Simply repeat the `\D+(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` part. Note that if you can't guarantee that the line will contain 3 numbers, you should probably use `[^\d\r\n]` instead of `\D` to avoid capturing numbers in the following line(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can do the job :

```
^.*?(?:\d+(?:,\d+)?)\D+(\d+(?:,\d+)?)
```

then you can access the second number using `group(1)`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/K009z3/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
Total(?:[^\d\r\n]*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)){2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uAcFPg/1).

I replaced `\s*` (zero or more whitespaces) with `[^\d\r\n]*` (zero or more chars other than digits, CR and LF chars) to match across any non-digit chars, not just whitespaces, and replaced `{1}` (it is always redundant) with `{2}`, to get to the second occurrence.